# Can you recommend a rabbi or community leader willing to speak about the harm of loud simcha music?

Tags: music, torts-damages, hearing, parties-celebrations, deaf

I recently published an article in the [Five Towns Jewish Times](http://5tjt.com/stop-the-noise/) that addresses the damage that loud *simcha* music does to hearing.

I have approached a few rabbis in my neighborhood and asked them to distribute the article and speak about this issue to their congregants. So far, the reaction has been ambivalence. The approx. 7 people I have spoken to have all acknowledged that it is a problem. Some thanked me for addressing the issue, openly (nice to get a "thanks", at least from SOMEONE, I guess?) But, essentially, I am getting the usual "yeshivish" shoulder shrug and hand waving attitude that says, "That's nice, but the problem is so prevalent, that there's nothing I could do that would stop it or make any difference, because no one will listen to me, anyway."

I'm really furious about this type of attitude. I also refuse to accept that there is absolutely no one notable or with clout that is willing to lend support on this issue. If you are aware of anyone who is willing to speak about this issue, regardless of where he is located in the world, I would appreciate knowing who and how I can contact this person.

In advance, thanks for your help and understanding.

Comment: You may get more mileage out of asking for rabbis who *have* spoken or written about this issue. It's hard to tell, a priori, what people are willing to support.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I can't argue with your suggestion. However, other than Rabbi Forsythe, whom I mentioned in my article, I know of no others. I have trouble contacting Rabbi Forsythe. The link on his web site to his email is "dead" and he didn't list a phone number or other contact info.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37453

Comment: When I was at my cousin's wedding a couple of months ago, I couldn't even stay in the room for much of the time due to the loud music combined with my sensitive hearing.

Comment: There was a piece on this in one of the Jewish weekly magazines (Hamodia? Mishpacha?) in the past few years ...that might be a good place to start. I do recall that frum doctors and audiologists were quoted there, but I don't recall a specific rabbi who was quoted

Comment: Dan, why doesn't the answer to the question that @msh210 cited satisfy this question, as well? (For the record, I don't think that they're duplicates)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, he already asked that: see my comment, above.

Comment: @Shokhet msh210's link is actually my own question, and the answer, there, indicates just one current person, Rabbi Forsythe, whom I spoke about in my prev. comment. OK, now that I wrote the article, I'm onto the next step, which is why I asked my current question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about Judaism. It is not even looking for practical guidance regarding performing a mitzvah; e.g. I want to perform the mitzvah of saving a life on my friend with ribose-5-phosphate isomerase deficiency. How can I help him. Rather, it seeks information in order to attempt the equivalent.